# "Session has not been configured for this application or request" en controlador Asíncrono de AspNet vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Saludos,

Agradezco ayuda con el siguiente tema que ya me está matando la cabeza.
Utilizando AspNet vNext **(1.0.0-rc1-update1)** he tenido problemas para acceder a datos de sesión desde un controlador para WebApi.

De manera aleatoria (a veces si, a veces no), aparece este error:

> “Session has not been configured for this application or request”

adicionalmente, se produce una

> “InvalidOperationException”

y el objeto HttpContext.Session es nulo.

He leído la documentación (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html) y allí indica que si se trata de acceder al objeto “*Session*” antes de utilizar el middleware “*UseSession*” se produce esta excepción. También en varios hilos de StackOverflow (inglés) como este: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801631/unable-to-use-session-in-asp-net-vnext-project o https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814042/using-tempdata-is-crashing-my-application entre otros; y recomiendan re-organizar las llamadas a los middlewares del método “*Configure*” de la clase "*StartUp*" de tal manera que el middleware “*UseSession*” se utilice antes de invocar al middleware “*UseMvc*”.

Tengo clara la importancia de que las invocaciones a los middlewares en el método “*Configure*” sean en un estricto orden de tal manera que el pipeline de la petición reaccione de manera coherente a los middlewares y para probar he ido “subiendo” el llamado a “*UseSession*” y en este momento el middleware “*UseSession*” es el primero en el método “*Configure*” pero no consigo que esta excepción siga ocurriendo.

Inicialmente pensé que el hecho de intentar utilizar el objeto “session" desde un controlador para WebApi podría ser el causante del error, sin embargo, como he comentado, este error no ocurre siempre sino de manera aleatoria.

También en algunos post de StackOverflow he leído que colocando un

> “using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;”

lo cual (en mi poco conocimiento de C#) no tiene mucho sentido ya que el “*using*” por sí solo no hace nada (salvo que se utilizaran métodos de extensión), para el caso, el “*using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;*” no tiene ningún efecto, de hecho, tanto “CodeMaid” como “ReSharper” marcan esta línea como “*RedundantUsingDirective*”.

Como medida adicional para intentar hacer funcionar mi controlador, he intentado utilizar los features de Http, pero estos también aparecen nulos de manera aleatoria.
He creado una propiedad para acceder al objeto Session, así:

```
protected ISession Session => (HttpContext.Session ?? HttpContext.Features.Get<ISession>())??HttpContext.Features.Get<ISessionFeature>()?.Session;
```

Agradezco si alguno sabe cómo puedo lidiar con este problema que ya no me deja ni dormir.

Muchas gracias.

***Actualización:***

Como coloqué en los comentarios, encontré que este error solo se presenta cuando el controlador donde intento acceder al objeto sesión tiene operaciones asíncronas (Async/Await). He cambiado un poco la lógica del controlador para dejarlo totalmente síncrono (sin llamadas await) y el error desaparece (Creo que la aleatoriedad que hablaba inicialmente se debía a las pruebas que estaba haciendo).

Aunque realmente no sé si se trate de un bug, realmente me gustaría volver a dejar todo asíncrono como lo tenía. Agradezco si alguien sabe porque funciona siendo síncrono y deja de funcionar siendo asíncrono.

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, he probado a acceder a la sesión desde una tarea asíncrona y a mi me ha funcionado, he actualizado mi respuesta con el ejemplo de código. ¿Podrías poner algo el código que muestre como estas haciendo tu las operaciones asíncronas?

Answer (score 6):

Para usar la sesión en un proyecto de ASP.NET Core (a.k.a ASPNET vNext, a.k.a ASPNET5) hay que añadir la referencia `Microsoft.AspNet.Session`

Después hay que configurar el uso de sesiones en el pipeline de OWIN añadiendo las llamadas a `AddSession()` y `AddCaching()` en el método `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` del archivo `startup.cs`

```
// Add MVC services to the services container.
services.AddMvc();
services.AddCaching(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of     IDistributedCache
services.AddSession();
```

Por último, hay que añadir una llamada a `UseSession()` justo antes de configurar las rutas de Mvc

```
// IMPORTANT: This session call MUST go before UseMvc()
app.UseSession();

// Add MVC to the request pipeline.
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    // Uncomment the following line to add a route for porting Web API 2 controllers.
    // routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id?}");
});
```

De esta manera ya podrás usar la sesión en tus controladores

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "Ben Rules!");
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Test");

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Los ejemplos de código los he obtenido de [este](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/) artículo en inglés donde lo explican de forma detallada pero no he tenido tiempo de probarlo personalmente. Ya contarás si te funciona.

**Actualización:** También se puede acceder a los valores de las variables de sesión desde una tarea asíncrona usando `async/await`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> About()
{
    var task = new Task<string>(() => {
        var count = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Contador");

        if (count.HasValue)
            count++;
        else
            count = 1;

        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Contador", count.Value);
        return $"Mensaje desde tarea asíncrona [{count}]";
    });
    task.Start();

    ViewData["Message"] = await task;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @rsciriano Si, seguí la guía tal cual como la mencionan en el enlace que compartes y en otros, pero no funciona.
Pero parece que ya encontré algo de luz en el problema y al parecer el problema solo se produce cuando se intenta acceder al objeto Session desde un controlador con operaciones asíncronas (async / await). Removí todas las operaciones asíncronas en donde utilizaba el objeto sesssion y las convertí en operaciones síncronas y ya funciona bien.
Me gustaría cambiar la pregunta (el título) pero no sé si sea adecuado. No sé si se deba eliminar esta… y crear otra.

Comment: @CamiloBernal De nada. En cuanto lo de la pregunta, quizás lo mejor sea que la edites aunque la cambies por completo. Por mi respuesta no te preocupes que casi fue un copy/paste+traducción de este artículo que tenía a mano porque estoy preparando un taller para el martes que viene en [EINA Unizar](https://twitter.com/EINAunizar). Cuando tengas la nueva pregunta te intentaré responder. Saludos