# Sessiones en ASP .NET Core 1.0 y ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy haciendo una serie de pruebas en ASP .NET MVC Core 1.0 para ver si es conveniente migrar el proyecto de MVC 4 a MVC Core 1.0 muchos de los errores que me salieron ya están corregidos.

Tengo problemas al pasar los parámetros que contiene `sesionManange`:

```
sesionManage.cuenta = WAutofactura_Respuesta.email;
sesionManage.devKey = WAutofactura_Respuesta.DevKey;
sesionManage.schema = WAutofactura_Respuesta.Schema;
sesionManage.mobileKey = WAutofactura_Respuesta.MobileKey;
```

el cual el problema es esta linea:

```
HttpContext.Session["sessionManage"] = sesionManage;
```

Entonces mi pregunta es **¿Como puedo pasar los parámetros de la variable `sesionManange` a una variable `HttpContext.Session` en ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0?**

**EDIT 1**
Investigando un poco mas en las variables de sesión encontré este metodo para serializar mi modelo de `sesionManange`:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        where T : class
    {
        var json = session.GetString(key);
        if (json == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
    public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        session.SetString(key, json);
    }
}
```

El cual me marca errores en `GetObject<T>` y `SetObject`, este es el error que me marca:

> Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; SessionExtensions is a nested class

Comment: la verdad es que no encuentro ninguna relacion entre el Session y el codigo del SessionExtensions, esa extension solo permite serializar/deserializar un objeto json que asignes a la session, pero no resuelve un problema de acceso a esta

Comment: dice que hay problema con HttpContext.Session, pero cual seria el problema? algun mensaje de error. Esa sesionManage que mencionas es una clase creada por ti?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini `SessionExtensions` es una clase creada por mi la cual me va a permitir hacer un serializar el modelo de `sesionManage` y almacenarlo en una variable de sesión y el error que me muestra lo puse en la pregunta

Comment: Hola en [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5459/602) explicaba como se trabaja con las sesiones en ASP.NET Core, quizás te sirva

Answer (score 2):

Estoy algo tarde para responder esta pregunta, pero basado en el hecho de que acabo de terminar un proyecto con similares caracteristicas me parecio interesante compartir con la comunidad porque todos nosotros trabajamos con **Legacy Code** todo el tiempo.

Primero decir que migrar un projecto MVC4 para .Net Core 1.0, 2.0,..., 3.1 es una tarea interesante pero el area de seguridad en mi opinion personal es una de las mas interesantes. Destacar que en terminos de seguridad el mundo se ha alejado de la utilizacion de las Session/Cookies por multiples razones:

1. Escalabilidad
2. Seguridad
3. Integracion con WebApi

Por solo mencionar las que me han dado dolores de cabeza. En cambio la tendecia en la comunidad de desarrolladores y especialistas de seguridad es JWT, IdentityServers y OAuth2, una investigacion le puede dar una buena idea de como implementar seguridad cuando realize la migracion, y sobre todo es extremadamente util si esta integrando crea SPA(Single Page Application) o PWA (Progressive Web Application) con alguno de los nuevos frameworks de javascript(typescript) Angular, ReactJS o Vue.

Gracias y si tiene alguna pregunta con gusto le respondo.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

El error que te da no tiene que ver con las sesiones si no con que la clase `SessionExtensions` está anidada dentro de otra y las clases estáticas que definen métodos de extensión no pueden estar anidadas dentro de otras.

Sácala fuera y por lo menos no de dará ese error.